# IIS Manager - find site based on physical path

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

There are 50+ sites in IIS.
I know the specific app's physical path is:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SomeSite
How do I quickly find it among sites list, without clicking one by one and explore or analizing Advanced Settings -> Physical path

(Don't tell me: keep it tidy and call it the same name as folder, because I'm not owner nor administrator nor creator etc. it's all somebody elses sites, and I'm the bad guy who tells others "keep it tidy". P.S. it's production, I can't tidy it up myself as I would wish)

I looked it up, and couldn't find similar question, I can't believe others don't have issue with it, I have it often so I finnaly decided to ask here...

Comment: Most IIS experts will go directly to applicationHost.config and perform a text search, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig No need to bother IIS Manager.

Comment: thanks. However, I had some tasks to do there

Answer (score 0):

Found the satisfying way:

Sites

there's the list and I can sort it by path

I should browse the list to find it.

Better than the current solution, but I would prefer if someone can actually tell me how to do it quicker.